# Preferred way to read from an existing-format endian-variable binary file

Tags: c#

I'd like to read DWARF information from binary file in C#. I know there are C libraries out there to do this, but for my exercise, I'm reading the file entirely with C# / .NET. DWARF has a common header and then the rest of the information may be stored Little-endian or Big-endian depending on what's specified in the header. I'd like to support both formats. DWARF is just an example--this question is about reading and writing binary files (with an existing format) in general. I can think of several ways to attack the problem:

## Entirely Custom Binary Reader

A custom reader takes a binary stream as input and exposes it's output as `IEnumerable<DwarfTypeX>` or `IList<DwarfTypeX>`. When the user reads from the properties in the reader, it goes and parses data from the binary stream byte-by-byte using state-machines, etc. If the machine architecture doesn't match the file architecture, the parser reads the bytes in reverse and writes them into the structure or array elements in reverse to correct endianness.

## Marshaling

This is similar to the approach above except that we use `Marshal.StructureToPtr` to pull an entire chunk of binary data from the stream and shove it into a structure. However, endianness then needs to be corrected in a separate step. Either each property on the resulting object knows how to convert its backing store to the machine's endianness, or the backing stores are swapped around explicitly after the marshaling.

## Custom IFormatter and Serialization

The Formatter implements `public object Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)` and returns an object. This precludes random partial parsing of the input stream. It's my understanding that this method must return its object fully-parsed.

Is there a best-practices way of reading binary files (with an existing format) in C# / .NET? I've seen plenty of examples of binary serialization where the format *hasn't* already been defined.

Comment: The marshaller is not for reading files. Deserialization is not for reading (arbitrary) files. If you want read files, *read files*. It's a common and pernicious misconception that copying bytes from files directly into memory structures is a reliable way to do business. It's not even true for unmanaged code, and it's doubly untrue for managed code. As to the *best* approach for reading the files and then interpreting the data, there isn't one. It depends on your needs for memory, processing speed and access patterns of the data.

Comment: @Jeroen - Thanks. That's useful info. Care to put this into an answer?Specifically, can you expand upon why Marshaling and Serialization really are inappropriate? (I'm guessing it has something to do with security, versioning, and data validation). What you've already stated in your comment answers my question.